# How do I realiably use the airstrikes in Homefront?

Tags: homefront

I've recently picked up Homefront and am thoroughly enjoying it.  One of the main reasons I like it over the CoD games is that getting your special purchases (equivalent to killstreak rewards) doesn't require you to be insanely good (and/or lucky) since you can save up the points during a game for something like an airstrike.  This benefits players like me who can rack up 2/3 kills in a row but rarely more while not penalising the hardcore players who rack up lots of points anyway since they can afford to use the purchases more often.

But what frustrates me is that the airstrikes seem to very hard to aim, there is no obvious way afaict to distinguish between friendly and enemy soldiers from the targetting screen.  Vehicles are not relevant here because the cursor does change to red when hovering over an enemy vehicle.

This difficulty in targetting is very irritating when you've saved up for an airstrike for most of the game only to have it hit nothing (or on one unfortunate ocassion myself)!

Is there some way to easily spot enemy targets when using the airstrikes or do I just have to rely on luck and recognising the rough position of the enemy when I spawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this got fixed in one of the patches since when I played it again in the past couple of months red enemy highlights had been added to the airstrike targetting screens much to my pleasure :-)